# How can I write a file in VxWorks shell

Tags: file-io, vxworks

I am trying to write a file in VxWorks using something like

```
saveFd = open("myfile.txt",0x102, 0777 )
oldFd = ioGlobalStdGet(1)
ioGlobalStdSet(1, saveFd)
d 0xfea00100, 4 
ioGlobalStdSet(1, oldFd)
```

But I am unnable to perform the file creation / writing.
Here is the output:

```
-> saveFd = open("myfile.txt",0x102, 0777 )
saveFd = 0x1fbfb040: value = -1 = 0xffffffff
-> ioGlobalStdSet(1, saveFd)
dvalue = -1 = 0xffffffff
```

How can I create a file with the desired output?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your system have an actual file system onboard?  if you do an "ls" from the shell, what do you get?  If it shows files from your host, you are probably using netDrv which is actually using FTP. Don't know that you would be able to use regular file operations with that. I would also check write permission on the FTP server.

Comment: ls command also returns "-1".
Could I write the file in the host with something like
`
      hostAdd "winxp", "ip"
      #netDevCreate "winxp:", "winxp", 0
      netDevCreate ("winxp:", "winxp", 1)
    
      saveFd = open("winxp:C:/myfile.txt",0x102, 0777 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something wrong with 'flags' parameter passed to 'open'. Correct type of accesses:

```
O_RDONLY (0)    (or READ)   - open for reading only.
O_WRONLY (1)    (or WRITE)  - open for writing only.
O_RDWR (2)  (or UPDATE) - open for reading and writing.
O_CREAT (0x0200)        - create a file.
```

The flags passed to open should 'OR' the flags. Like this:

`O_CREAT | O_RDWR = 0x202`

With this parameter you may get something like this (if you have a host ftp properly connected):

```
-> saveFd = open("myfile.txt",0x202,0777)
New symbol "saveFd" added to kernel symbol table.
saveFd = 0x8a9bf90: value = 5 = 0x5
->
```

(Make sure you have a write permission granted on the ftp host server.)

Comment: pardon, how can we see the content of `myfile.txt`?

Comment: @MortezaLSC, you can 'cat' the content on server side.

Comment: It is possible like so: `-> readBuf = malloc(100)
-> fd = open("/RAM1/myFile", 2)
-> read(fd, readBuf, 100)
-> printf readBuf`